# Accessing the data model from several classes in a JavaFX application

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm creating a JavaFX application which implements the concept of a view, a view controller and a data model. The view controller creates an instance of the data model and defines some bindings on properties. So far, this works fine.

Now, there is another class which implements some business logic. This class also needs access to the data model as it uses a subset of these data.

What would be an appropritate way to "share" this data model between the view controller and the business logic?

- Using a singleton for the data model?
- Passing the data model instance to the business logic?
- ...